# reCAPTCHA always fails to validate

Tags: php, recaptcha

I have the following function that I use for Google recaptcha:

```
function isNotSpam(){
    if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
        try {
            $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
            $data = ['secret'   => $google_captcha_secert,
                     'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
                     'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']];
            $options = [
                'http' => [
                    'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                    'method'  => 'POST',
                    'content' => http_build_query($data) 
                ]
            ];
            $context  = stream_context_create($options);
            $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
            return json_decode($result)->success;
        }catch (Exception $e) {return null;}
    }else{return null;}
}
```

Then I check for errors this way:

```
    $google_captcha_secert = "/my secret key here/";
    if(!isNotSpam()){display error here}
```

My HTML contains the following code for reCAPTCHA

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=en"></script>
</head>
<body>
...
<form>
...
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="/ my public key here /"></div>
...
</form>
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried checking for errors by using the function without the !function and using it this way instead:

```
if(isNotSpam()){}else{display error here}
```

I tried to do it with

```
if(isNotSpam() == null){display error here}
```

Nothing is working, it always tells me that I am a robot, but this obviously is incorrect. Can you tell me where the mistake is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$google_captcha_secert` is not defined inside your function, because you neither imported it from the global scope using the [`global` keyword](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.global), nor provided it as a parameter to your function.

There might be further errors, consider logging error responses / exceptions, instead of silently swallowing them in order to be able to debug this kind of issues yourself. I also recommend enabling error_reporting when debugging. PHP should have printed a notice there.